# How to created xsd and java class from xml

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I want to create xml like this (element Element is no required (minOccurs=0))

```
<Root>
    <ns:Element date="1980-02-06" state="S">Value1</ns:Element>
    <ns:Element date="1980-02-06" state="S">Value2</ns:Element>
    <ns:Element date="1980-02-06" state="N" xsi:nil="true" />
</Root>
```

so in XSD I created element:

```
        <xs:element name="Element" type="ElementType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
```

but problem is that plugin which I am using (cxf-codegen-plugin) create class which contains:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Element")
protected List<ElementType> element;
```

and not

`protected List<JAXBElement<ElementType>> element;`

which I expected because now I have no options to set nillable. When I remove nillable="true" from xsd then there is no change and the same java code is generated. So what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I propably found how to fix it. When I add to bindings.xml this:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Element']">
    <jaxb:class name="MyCustomElementType"/>    
</jaxb:bindings>
```

then it create new inner static class which belong to Element:

```
    public static class MyCustomElementType
        extends JAXBElement<ElementType>
    { ...
}
```

which is what I want.